# Reusing TCP sockets while using proxy servers for GET requests

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, web-crawler

I am trying to reuse TCP connections while making HTTP requests. Specifically I am trying to reuse TCP sockets I get while making a `CONNECT` request to proxy servers, but the sockets are destroyed by the time I am trying to reuse them. I am not sure where my implementation is wrong.

Sample code:

```js
private connect(urlString: string, proxy: AxiosProxyConfig)
{
    const url = new URL(urlString), connectStart = Date.now()

    return new Promise<Socket>((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = http.request({
            method: "CONNECT",
            host: proxy.host,
            path: url.host,
            port: proxy.port,
            agent: new http.Agent({
                keepAlive: true,
                keepAliveMsecs: 10,
                timeout: 30000
            }),
            headers: {
                "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
                "Proxy-Authorization": `Basic ${Buffer.from(proxy.auth?.username + ":" + proxy.auth?.password).toString('base64')}`,
            }
        })

        req.on("connect", (_, socket) => {
            this.sockets.set(proxy.host + proxy.port, socket) // save the socket for further reuse
            return resolve(socket)
        })
        
        req.on("error", (e) => {
            return reject(e)
        })

        req.end()
    })
}

private newRequest(urlString: string)
{
    const url = new URL(urlString), proxy = this.proxyStack.get()

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let socket = this.sockets.get(proxy.host + proxy.port) // try to obtain a socket. whenever I get a socket from this, it is already destroyed (socket.destroyed === true)

        if (!socket) // if a socket is not found, create it first
        {
            socket = await this.connect(urlString, proxy)
        }

        const agent = new https.Agent({ socket })

        https.get({
            host: url.host,
            path: url.href,
            agent,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "User-Agent": "axios/0.27.2",
            }
        }, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200)
            {
                return reject(res.statusCode)
            }

            let chunks: Buffer[] = []

            res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
            .on('end', () => {
                resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString())
            })
            .on("error", (e) => {
                return reject(e)
            })
        }).on("error", (e) => {
            return reject(e)
        }).end()
    })
}
```

Comment: Assuming that it's not the proxy that's closing the connection, one thing to consider is that you're creating a new agent for each request, where instead you likely have to create one global agent and use that for all requests (from looking at your code, it seems you initially tried to get regular keep-alive working and when that failed, you started implementing a sort of socket cache yourself?).

Comment: I didn't know the agent has functionality of managing sockets, I see the properties which would imply so now. I can have one http agent, but I still need to make a new https agent everytime, no? Or maybe I should move my https agents into my "cache"? Otherwise I don't know how to "feed" the socket into the https agent as there doesn't seem to be any method.

Comment: The agent should do what you're trying to implement yourself (_"An Agent is responsible for managing connection persistence and reuse for HTTP clients"_), provided that your proxy actually supports keep-alive connections, otherwise your whole exercise is moot. You should use a single global agent.

Comment: It doesn't let me use one agent though. The proxies are not working on HTTPS and the website is not working via HTTP (I get redirected to HTTPS). I get ERR_BAD_PROTOCOL in each variant. The sockets dictionary on http agent is empty even though I have just one agent for all the CONNECT requests, thus I am contacting the proxy provider.